# Server 2012 DFS New Member Issue

Tags: replication, windows-server-2012, dfs, server-crashes

I am trying to add a new member to our DFS topology. We have 3 DCs (VMs - VMware) running Windows server 2012, two servers are located in or Primary site and the third at our DR site. Currently the two servers at our primary site are currently replicating DFS (full mesh) and are working fine.

I have tried several times to add the third DC to our DFS topology, every time i configure the  replication path e.g E:\MSI and click ok the MMC snap in crashes. Below is the crash info, any idea what is causing this? What i am doing is fairly straight forward and don't see why this would be happening.

Windows Crash Error:

```
gnature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: mmc.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 6.2.9200.16496
  Problem Signature 03: 50ece2e8
  Problem Signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18046
  Problem Signature 06: 51552cda
  Problem Signature 07: 6291
  Problem Signature 08: 25
  Problem Signature 09: RML5K4UDBMA5NI04CIYRWVDHKEWFDHCV
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: b979
  Additional Information 2: b97911c958b3d076b53a1d80c1c56088
  Additional Information 3: 4fee
  Additional Information 4: 4fee5b9baabd694859b15dfc5e1863b7
    
Crash Report

Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=130165974300817209
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=d15d0d38-dd36-11e2-93fb-005056af764c
IntegratorReportIdentifier=d15d0d37-dd36-11e2-93fb-005056af764c
NsAppName=mmc.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
Sig[0].Value=mmc.exe
Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
Sig[1].Value=6.2.9200.16496
Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
Sig[2].Value=50ece2e8
Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
Sig[3].Value=System.Windows.Forms
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=4.0.30319.18046
Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
Sig[5].Value=51552cda
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=6291
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=25
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=RML5K4UDBMA5NI04CIYRWVDHKEWFDHCV
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=3081
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=b979
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=b97911c958b3d076b53a1d80c1c56088
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=4fee
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=4fee5b9baabd694859b15dfc5e1863b7
UI[2]=C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe
UI[3]=Microsoft Management Console has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\MFC42u.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\mmcbase.DLL
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\UxTheme.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\SHCORE.DLL
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16579_none_418ab7ef718b27ef\Comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\mmcndmgr.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\system32\xmllite.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\fa44d07a6b592198dfeae841489f295b\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\system32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\577825eedb03a45fd7327050e85d0c44\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\MMCEx\9b714b187bfb304526df6d4e6160e15c\MMCEx.ni.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\MMCFxCommon\3804721e3998fdf29b06e86bcfe92eb8\MMCFxCommon.ni.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Configuration\e3873005e8829578178618d41d012849\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\aea95442f7e98cffc3c849fe3b0658d6\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\f28da0d8140095c5c86e9f2443878807\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\c2f5f2174cecd9faaf74a0cdeebfdd49\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.Mff1be75b#\3c16df28b2935a005a7fd0da96e0ff6c\Microsoft.ManagementConsole.ni.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\DfsMgmt\ed2ebd5dc4469285040f2e21c5e990dc\DfsMgmt.ni.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\DfsObjectModel\43ed7ca19e7c26cbf27c5c8a2e0fec93\DfsObjectModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\CfsCommonUIFx\aea54a98ed63ebeaa6703e9f0a724ac8\CfsCommonUIFx.ni.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Interop.DFSRHelper\3780b83ee96c137664d8807e7042768f\Interop.DFSRHelper.ni.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.16384_none_7762d5fd3178b04e\comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9200.16518_none_726fbfe0cc22f012\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\DWrite.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\system32\Netapi32.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\system32\clusapi.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptdll.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\system32\DFSCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Dired13b18a9#\0acd265b442254788d2d1429c296558c\System.DirectoryServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\system32\ntdsapi.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\system32\LOGONCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\system32\activeds.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\system32\adsldpc.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\system32\adsldp.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\system32\DSPARSE.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\system32\msv1_0.DLL
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\system32\DSROLE.DLL
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Dire5d62f0a2#\819205bfacb57978948171e414993369\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ni.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\System32\objsel.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\System32\Secur32.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\System32\credui.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\System32\DPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\system32\riched32.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\system32\RICHED20.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\system32\msls31.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\System32\Bcp47Langs.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Serv759bfb78#\e44b9230fcc7dc263820eff07cfc6353\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\system32\kerberos.DLL
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Accessibility\e69795104b16b74fe9c1e7dff4f3f510\Accessibility.ni.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=Microsoft Management Console
AppPath=C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8

Application Log Event ID: 1000
Faulting application name: mmc.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16496, time stamp: 0x50ece2e8
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988aa6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000003811c
Faulting process id: 0xd30
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce71411a7b775b
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d15d0d37-dd36-11e2-93fb-005056af764c
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Application Log Event ID: 1026

Application: mmc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.ThemingScope.DeactivateActCtx(Int32 dwFlags, IntPtr lpCookie)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInMessagePumpProxy.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.ISnapInMessagePumpProxy.Run()
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInThread.OnThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```